# Unnatural AD9850 Output Attenuation

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi, high-frequency, dds, frequency-synthesis

Yes, another question about this DDS. However, I think mine is sufficiently different from the others I've read.

I purchased an AD9850 board on Amazon for $17 from "NooElec" ([see here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085N592S)). I've been testing it out tonight, and it operates very strangely. I've read where these AD9850 PCBs (often made in China) sometimes use fake chips or have bad designs. Mine seems to have shipped from the US, but its country of origin is questionable.

I'm given to understand that the DDS output attenuates at higher frequencies. However, I've been playing with my board hooked to my oscilloscope, and there is gross attenuation output for frequencies as low as 5 MHz. (The chip itself is designed for 60+ MHz). In fact, the output voltage increases and decreases repeatedly with increasing frequency. Some sample points:

- 100 kHz: 1.13 Vpp
- 500 kHz: 1.08 Vpp (same)
- 1 MHz: 1.1.08 Vpp (same)
- 2 Mhz: 1.15 Vpp (slight increase)
- 3 MHz: 1.38 Vpp (mega increase)
- 4 Mhz: 1.32 Vpp (slight decrease)
- 5 MHz: 0.975 Vpp (mega decrease)
- 6 MHz: 0.660 Vpp (mega decrease)
- 7 MHz: 0.220 Vpp (mega decrease)
- 8 Mhz: 0.400 Vpp (mega increase)
- 9 Mhz: 0.400 Vpp (same)
- 10 Mhz: 0.150 Vpp (mega decrease)
- 20 MHz: 0.340 Vpp (mega increase)
- 30 Mhz: 0.150 Vpp (mega decrease)
- 60 Mhz: 0.150 Vpp (same)

This is the only frequency synthesizer I've used (except for some lab-quality function generators). Should I be expecting this kind of weird behavior from a AD9850 board? I understand the output can attenuate, but can it really attenuate so much so quickly and then increase again? Or do I just have a bad board?

Note that I'm not using filters on the output. If you're curious, I'm operating the board with a Raspberry Pi 2 and code from [Tom Herbison](http://asliceofraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2013/10/connecting-dds-module-to-raspberry-pi.html).

Comment: What kind of wave is it? Sine? And how are you connecting it to the scope?

Comment: It's a sine wave. I hooked it to the scope several ways: direct connection to out pin, in series with a capacitor on the out pin (of the size recommended by Tom), and on the capacitor with a resistive load on parallel with it forming roughly a 70 MHz LPF as recommended on one web page I'd read.

Comment: Looks like a rather long and un-terminated cable connection to the scope, with several reflections.

Comment: Unterminated? The RC filter was terminated. I mean, I could try putting a resistive load I'm series with a DC-blocking capacitor. (And terminate it, of course.)

Comment: How would you suggest testing it? I know the concepts, but frequency synthesis is new to me.

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your oscilloscope? Us there any possibility of this being a measurement problem?

Comment: I purchased it "like new" from a company recently. I haven't used it much, but it has the factory's certificate of calibration. The BW is 70 MHz with a 1GS/s sample rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the AD9850 board from NooElec, purchased on Amazon.  However, the unit I bought was described for up to 40 MHz. I used it to build Antenna Analyzer

[image]

I measure voltage at the junction of C1 and R2. There is a Low Pass filter on the 9850 board.  So I am measuring after the filter. On the 9850 board, there is a 200 ohm resistor to ground before the LP Filter, and also another 200 ohm resistor to ground at output of filter. [This contains schematic](http://www.qrp-labs.com/images/ultimate3mod6m/ddsmodule.pdf) of what I believe is on my 9850 board.

I measure + 0.300 volts peak, and - 0.300 volts peak (.6v peak to peak) very flat from 1 MHz to 30 MHz.  Then voltage drop off begins at 30 MHz up to 40 MHz.  I don't see the wobbling output similar to yours from 2 to 20 MHz.

Not sure if this qualifies as an answer, but too large for a comment.  But at the least it might give you a comparison to your results.

EDIT 1  :  The output of the AD9850 IC (not the board) is a current, so output voltage will be dependent upon the resistor you choose to use as a load on the AD9850 output.  "Pin 21 IOUT Analog Current Output of the DAC"

Comment: 1) A homebrew antenna analyzer? AWESOME!

Comment: 2) This actually does help me quite a bit. Even at 10 MHz, I can't get a steady sine wave output but rather a funky-shaped wave with other waves visibly inside of it and an FFT showing harmonics out the wazoo. I tried this morning to measure the wave across various capacitors and a 200 Ω resistive load in series. I'm aware the output is current and not voltage, but even adding this load doesn't help me.

Comment: 3) Based on your seemingly easy use of the board and my difficulty getting it to even put out a pure-ish sinusoid, I'm concluding it's defective.

Comment: 4) It's worth noting the following new piece of information in the description of the NooElec Amazon listing: "After the 20-30MHz frequency harmonics increases, the waveform will be less and less clean."

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "resistive load in series".  If you are measuring at pin 21 of the AD9850,  the resistor would be from pin 21 to ground.

Comment: From to Iout, then to capacitor, then to resistor, then to ground. I meant the R & C are in series with each other.

Comment: That might be the problem.  The AD9850 doesn't show an output equivalent,  but with your de-coupling capacitor in series with the resistor, might be messing up some internal bias in the output circuit.  Try the resistor to ground.  Then use de-coupling capacitor to remove the DC for your output.

Comment: I tried resistor to ground this morning. It made no difference other than allow the DC through :(

Comment: Marla, I was planning to use the AD9850 in the final project for my MSEE, but I wound up leaving it out. (The project focus was on IF-signal generation for a SDR transmitter, and the hardware portion of the project became too much to implement in one semester.) Still, I appriciate your help, and I want you to know that I thanked you by name in the "Acknowledgements" section of my project report.

Comment: @wisner  -  Glad to hear the update.  Certainly your attempt was not a failure, rather a change in the design. Change like you made is a normal part of the sequence of design. Recognizing change is needed, instead of stubbornly persisting is a good mark.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar test with mine and I get a 1 V peak to peak voltage up to 10 MHz. I want to use it as a VFO for ham radio HF bands, so far so good, but its output voltage drops by half around 24 MHz. The DDS module crystal is supposed to be 125 MHz. The doc says that output amplitude is affected by a function of both output and clock frequency: 
\begin{equation}
y = sin(x)/x
\end{equation}
where: 
\begin{equation}
x = \pi (f_{out}/f_{osc})
\end{equation}
However, the calculated attenuation factor is 0.94 at 24 MHz, not 0.5 on both filtered and unfiltered outputs! Something is wrong with these bargain DDS modules for sure...